# Eclipse 4 declarative service injection in a declarative service

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, declarative-services

I am creating declarative services, lets call them Service1 and Service2.
Everything works fine in my eclipse RCP application.
Now I want my Service1 to be injected into Service2, so my Service2 class have a new field like this :

```
@Inject
Service1 myService1;
```

This never gets injected and Debugging a little the Declarative Service instanciation in Eclipse 4 (org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent) it seems that nothing get injected after the class has been instanciated.
Is this a limitation of the DS implementation in eclipse ?

Is there a way to fix this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible by default. You can make some utility class which is called on @Acivate which searching the coresponding service on tracker and sets the @Inject service with reflection, but in that case you will lose all of lifecycle, so its not a nice osgi way.

If you would line to use @Inject annotation you can use pax-cdi for that, but on that case you cannot use the declarative service annotations on that class - because in that case the pax will instantiate and register the service on the tracker.